# Build a CSV, and keep "," in entry string?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv

When writing a CSV, you obviously need to add a "," between every value, so that it can identify where to split the information, for example in an excel.

For example:

```
Name,Age
Bob,23
```

Will separate this data into 2 columns. However, in some circumstances, a field might contain a "," already.

```
Program,Version,Text
Hello_World,1,Hello, World!
```

This instance is going to split that into 4 columns, which we obviously don't want. An easy way to hack this is to use a `Regex.Replace` to change any existing "," characters to a ".' instead for example, but that then changes the value of the data.

Instead, is there any way I can change the value of the "," character so that the CSV doesn't recognise it as a "split" character, without actually adding characters, or changing the character to something else? Eg:

```
Program,Version,Text,Author
Hello_World,1,Hello, World!,Ben
```

So that is appears as:

```
Program     | Version | Text          | Author
Hello_World | 1       | Hello, World! | Ben
```

---

Post-note: creating a tab-delimited CSV is a simple solution, but I'm looking for other potential solutions, if they exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to enclose the field in double quotes:

```
Program,Version,Text,Author
Hello_World,1,"Hello, World!",Ben
```

When the field itself contains double quotes, those need to be escaped with another double quote:

```
"Monitor 24"", Samsung"
```

More information: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180